# System.windows.forms.tlb

Tags: vb6, com-interop

in the windows SDK there is this file residing in the Lib-directory. Is it possible to use this file with VB6? Google found nothing about it.
If not, in which language (Excep c++) can I use it?
resp. for what is it good for (yes, I know .net winforms)
Thanks regards
Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file provides the COM interface information for the .NET objects that are exposed via COM interop. You can't use it directly, as it only provides the interface information.